# How is the value of b unchanged?

Tags: c++

How is the value of `b` unchanged?

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int a = 5, b = 10;
    if (++a || ++b)
        std::cout << a << b;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

The output is `610`. But how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's how the 'if' statement works:

```
if(condition1 || condition2 || condition 3){
//do this
}
```

now if condition1 is true (which in your code, it is since a!=0), the execution straightaway moves inside the block without checking 2 and 3.

If you wish to increment b as well, try && in place of ||